# find number of records can store in sql server nvarchar(x)

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to find the way that can tell me how many characters I can store in `nvarchar(x)` where `X` is number... and also how many characters can be stored in

1. `nvarchar(1)`
2. `nvarchar(400)`
3. `nvarchar(1000)`

Many thanks

Comment: 1) 1   2) 400    3)1000

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 the manual states this, and I assume it hasn't changed in 2012:

> Character data types that are either fixed-length, nchar, or
>   variable-length, nvarchar, Unicode data and use the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.
>
> nchar [ ( n ) ]  Fixed-length Unicode character data of n characters.
>   n must be a value from 1 through 4,000. The storage size is two times
>   n bytes. The ISO synonyms for nchar are national char and national
>   character.
>
> nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]  Variable-length Unicode character data. n
>   can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size, in bytes, is two times
>   the number of characters entered + 2 bytes. The data entered can be 0
>   characters in length. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char
>   varying and national character varying.

Answer (score 0):

You can store x characters in nvarchar(x) variable.

If you are not sure of how many char you will need, you can use: nvarchar(max)